# Installing Dart Editor in Debian

Tags: dart

How to exactly install dart editor in debian? Tried to build dart from the source on this site [Building Dart on Debian](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/BuildingOnDebian) up to the **gclient runhooks** and ran

```
$ cd dart
$ ./tools/build.py -m release -a x64
```

which they say will build **ALL (including the dart editor w/c I prefer)**. But unluckily, the build fails after waiting a thousand years. Any ideas on how to properly install ALL the dart components on debian?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a while ago and failed building `Dartium` on Debian.
It might make sense to build the Dart runtime you use for the production server yourself but IMHO building DartEditor and Dartium is not worth the effort on Debian.

To install the development environment I just download the Linux package and unpack it.

Comment: That's the first thing I did and encountered the same problem on

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156843/dart-throwing-errors-on-linux-glibc-2-14-glibc-2-15-not-found

when I ran the test project sunflower to check if it works in the dart editor and led me to building dart on source